# Tool or Help-tip not applying to all multiple fields

Tags: html, css, tooltip

**Updated image after code change**

[image]

But from my below code  ,the 'help-tip' class appears for only one field.

The existing help tip which is appearing next to 'Enter Code number' field shows 'Enter Reg number!' on hover.  Why is it not applying for both the fields.

**UPDATED as per comments**

```
<div class="tabbed" >

  <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed1" type="radio" checked>
  <section>
    <h1>
      <label for="tabbed1">Legal Details</label>
    </h1>
    <div>
        <form name="Legal_details">
            <!--Begin: Help tip-->
                <span class="help-tip">
                <span > Enter your code number! </span>
                </span>
            <!--End: Help tip-->    
                <select selected="selected" name="code_number">
                    <option value="default">Enter Code number *</option>
                    <option value="title1">Code 1</option>
                    <option value="title2">Code 2</option>
                    <option value="title3">Code 3</option>
                    <option value="title4">Code 4</option>
                </select></br></br>

            <span class="help-tip">
                <span > Enter Reg number! </span>
            </span> 
            <input type="text" name="registration_number" size="25" placeholder="Registration Number *" required></br></br>             
       </form>
      </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Below is my .css:

**UPDATED as per comments**

```
.help-tip{
    position: relative;   /*UPDATED*/
    display:inline-block; 
    opacity:0.9;          
    top: 2px;
    left:253px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover span{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip span{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: 5px;            /* edited */
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip span:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    left:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip span:after{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: You need toinclude the full code, this isn't enough to help you.

Comment: Have updated the full code @Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probleme I think was in `position:absolute` also just put *the help-tip **after** it's corresponding input* .

so I managed to create a sample as Belllow :

```css
.help-tip{
    #position: relative;  /* removed */
    display:inline-block; /* added */
    opacity:0.9;          /* added */
    top: 7px;
    left: 165px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover span{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip span{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: 5px;            /* edited */
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip span:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    left:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip span:after{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbed" >

  <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed1" type="radio" checked>
  <section>
    <h1>
      <label for="tabbed1">Legal Details</label>
    </h1>
    <div>
        <form name="Legal_details">
             
            <select selected="selected" name="code_number">
                <option value="default">Enter Code number *</option>
                <option value="title1">Code 1</option>
                <option value="title2">Code 2</option>
                <option value="title3">Code 3</option>
                <option value="title4">Code 4</option>
            </select>
            <!--Begin: Help tip-->
            <span class="help-tip">
                <span > Enter your code number! </span>
            </span>
            <!--End: Help tip-->   <br><br>
            
            <input type="text" name="registration_number" size="25" placeholder="Registration Number *" required />
            <span class="help-tip">
                <span > Enter Reg number! </span>
            </span>
            <br><br>              
       </form>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats is the change you made, can you please highlight in css. i just copy pasted the same css i face the same issue

Comment: @Sach , I've added comment on your css ( added ,removed )
also it's important to put your help-tip after its input not before ! see my edited code

Comment: Have updated the code as per comments @bRIMOs, i still get only for 1st field

Comment: I think you have a cache problem or somthing like ( try to clear cache ctrl+f5 , ctrl+R), when you try the above snippet ,does it work fine ?

Comment: Oh crap ya...it was cache issue, i have updated the display, if i change to position: relative; and change the top and left values accordingly for the tip to appear next to each field, both the help-tips move together...

Comment: You want the tooltip to be next the help button ??

Comment: My pleasure :) .